# "Files to index up-front" in Eclipse Juno CDT

Tags: indexing, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

As mentioned in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/400465/945008/), eclipse has removed the option to index files "up-front" in Juno.

Unfortunately, this is a crucial feature in my project, and I'm looking for a workaround to add header files to be indexed even though they may not be included directly in the code.

Is anyone familiar with a method of doing this? Could I somehow "hack" the indexer by adding files external to the project? add it in the project file?